# How to call another function from LRESULT CALLBACK

Tags: c++, qt

Hi guys i want to call a function from `LRESULT` CALLBACK but it don't know this function when I call it in `LRESULT CALLBACK`

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MYLowLevelKeyBoardProc(int nCode,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
qDebug()<<"Key Pressed.";
do_eventFilter();
return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

bool MainWindow::do_eventFilter()
{
if (!_screenshotPending) {
        _screenshotPending=true;
        shootScreen();
        tt = new MYThread(&scaledPixmap, socket);
        QObject::connect(tt, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(quitThread()));
        tt->start();
        ui->label_3->setText(QString::number(i++));;
}
return false;
}
```

It give me this error:

`C3861: 'do_eventFilter': identifier not found`

It means this method does not known from in this function.

Comment: Your `do_eventFilter()` is a method of a class. Assuming it's a public member, you need to pass in an instance of the class to your function if you're going to call it.

Comment: thank you i did that but now it give me this error :  error: C3867: 'MainWindow::MYLowLevelKeyBoardProc': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member